# Spawn child to execute command shows more files on stdout.on('data') than actually exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, child-process, spawn

I want to zip a large directory $TMPDIR on Mac and want to track its progress. For that I am using following code:

```
let count = 0;
this.shellChildProcess = spawn("cd $TMPDIR;zip -r /Documents ." , [], {shell: true});
this.shellChildProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
     const updatedObjects: number = data.toString().match(new RegExp("updating", "g")) ? data.toString().match(new RegExp("updating", "g")).length : 0;
     const addedObjects: number = data.toString().match(new RegExp("adding", "g")) ? data.toString().match(new RegExp("adding", "g")).length : 0;
     count = count + Math.max(updatedObjects + addedObjects, 1);
     console.log(data + "count: " + count);
});
```

Partial output from this command looks like that:

[image]

Data is being received in chunks and i am parsing it to count files which are updated or added new in zip.

The total files that I get in return are 120708 with the zip command while actual file count is 63708. I got actual file count using following command on shell:

```
find . | wc -l
```

If I execute same command using spawn child, count remains same (63708). I am unable to track progress because of such a big difference in file count.

Comment: `Math.max(updatedObjects + addedObjects, 1)` what is the purpose of this operation?

Comment: @NullDev I edited the question to explain why i am doing that. Even if I skip this and count in a simple way "count = count + 1", the files that i receive on stdout are still more than actual files.

Comment: I figured out that all count commands (ls, find, du) are giving wrong count for .app .framework and such less known extensions. Not going into depth of some directories.